# Is it possible to get the length of a firebase JSON object when using vuefire?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vuejs2, vuefire

I have the following firebase JSON object:

```
"items" : {
  "111111111111" : {
      "ins" : {  <<<<<<<<< I want to display the length of this
        "1523878813443" : true,
        "1523878891312" : true,
        "1523878911379" : true,
        "1523879091312" : true
      },
      "name" : "10",
      "outs" : {  <<<<<<<<< and this one too
        "1523878813443" : true,
        "1523878891312" : true,
        "1523878911379" : true
      },
      "ownerID" : "QpMHsVHHRrMvk92rbSQvcYEv4en1"
    }
}
```

Here is the template part on where I am trying to get these values to update:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in items" >
     <td>
        {{item.childone - door.childtwo}}
     </td>
     <td>    
        {{item.childone}} 
      </td> 
      <td>
        {{item.childtwo}}
      </td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I got it to display the JSON object like this:

[image]

The **"In's"** column should display **4**, the **"Out's"** should display **3** and the **"Balance"** column should display **1**.
This is the firebase setup and data code on my component:

```
import firebase { doorsRef } from '../firebase-config';
export default {
  firebase() { 
    return {
      items: itemsRef,
    }
  },
...etc
}
```

Any kind soul out there who would be willing to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knowing that a JSON object has [**keys**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) (and values) I have used this on my template instead:

**{{Object.keys(**JSON.Object**).length}}**

So in my case this did the trick:

```
<tbody>
   <tr v-for="item in items" >
      <td>
         {{Object.keys(item.childone).length - Object.keys(item.childtwo).length}}
      </td>
      <td>    
         {{Object.keys(item.childone).length}} 
      </td> 
      <td>
         {{Object.keys(item.childtwo).length}} 
      </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

*Alternative you you can also count the number of [**values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values): **{{Object.values(***JSON.Object***).length}}***